# sort -z equivalent in Solaris ( support sorting of multi-line )

Tags: text-processing, sort

I'm looking for "sort -z" (supported only in GNU) equivalent in Solaris, so I could have multi-line "block" support.
I want to sort some text by chronological order ( date then time ), and that the sort will not break the text blocks in the process.

Example, I have:

```
2020-05-15:02:00:00:000 INFO[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:02:000 INFO[LF]
[HT]some extra data as second line[LF]
[HT]2020-05-15:02:00:01:000 INFO[LF]
[HT]some extra data as second line[LF]
[HT]some extra data as third line[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:04:000 INFO[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:03:000 INFO[LF]
```

- [HT] is horizontal tab key and [LF] is \n

and I wish it to be sorted into

```
2020-05-15:02:00:00:000 INFO[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:01:000 INFO[LF]
[HT]extra data as second line[LF]
[HT]some extra data as third line[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:02:000 INFO[LF]
[HT]extra data as second line[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:03:000 INFO[LF]
2020-05-15:02:00:04:000 INFO[LF]
```

on Centos/ubuntu (GNU) I manage to do that with:
    sort -zt : -k2,2 -k3,3n -k4,4n -k5,5n -k6,6n
 ( although not sure the milisec is being sorted ok ).

Please note:

1. I can't use msort - awk / sed / perl one-liner solutions are welcome.
2. each line is ending with LF, multi-line or not.
3. Multi lines ( 2nd line including and ahead ) starts with HF "tab" char.

Thanks :-)

Comment: GNU `sort -z` is to sort NUL-delimited records. Where are the NULs in your input?

Comment: What release of Solaris are you using? Do you have GNU `sort` available as `gsort`?

Comment: 1. Oracle Solaris 11.4

 2. just checked my log, it contains LF symbol at the end of each line including the multi-lines.
"sort -z" do work on that log while I use centos.

Comment: Just updated post:
there's HF at the start of each multi-line ( from 2nd line included and above ).
There's LF at the end of each line ( multi-line or not ).

Comment: OK I agree, the -"z" switch is massing up the sort... so I can't even use it on GNU.

Comment: I have a similat problem from a buggy mapfile implementation in the GNU linker that likes to see mapfiles in the inverted order. I use `tr` to change a block of lines into a single line, sort that and then revert the `tr` effect. See `MAPFILE_POST` macro in the files in directory `RULES` in the `schilytools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print sort /^\d.*\n(?:\D.*\n)*/gm' your-file
```

That loads the whole file in memory (slurp mode with `-0777 -p`), extracts the blocks based on that regexps (line starting (`^`) with a digit (`\d`) following 0 or more (`*`) lines starting with a non-digit (`\D`)) and `print`s them after `sort`ing.

Comment: That seems almost there to what I need... its wonderful - thanks.
how can I control how the sort is being done, per column with ":" being the delimiter ?
I what it chronologically, so date before time, H before M etc...

Comment: NM what I just wrote... issue is AFAIK that I need to zcat output of multiple text file before I pass it to perl... issue is that sort is working per file one by one, instead of sorting all the text from all the files togather.
is there a ways to perl directly from multiple gz compressed text files ?

Comment: @gps3dx, with that date format, to sort chronologically, you just need to sort lexically. `zcat ./*.gz... | perl ...` to process the concatenation of compressed files as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I already run it like you stated, but the output is sorted 1 file after the other chronologically - i.e not as a whole 1 big /large text.
i.e I do 'zcat *.gz | perl...' like you told me... output is:
2020-05-15:00:00:00:000
2020-05-15:01:00:00:000
2020-05-15:02:00:00:000
...
2020-05-15:23:59:00:000
2020-05-15:00:00:00:000
2020-05-15:01:00:00:000
2020-05-15:02:00:00:000

Comment: @gps3dx, if you want to sort them separately, you can do: `perl ... 'zcat file1.gz|' 'zcat file2.gz|' ...` or `for f in ./*.gz; do zcat "$f" | perl ...; done`

Comment: I might didn't communicate clearly - sorry.
I do NOT want them printed separately. I want to create 1 long sorted log that's built from multiple gz compressed text log. 'zcat *.gz | perl...' should do it - but it don't. sort scope is still within each file instead of being on all of them combined.
another example: I got 2 files A.gz and B.gz - A got '0\n1\n2\n' and B got '0\n1\n2\n' as content. after I do 'zcat *.gz | perl...' with the rest of the perl parms that you published, I get it sorted into a single output that its content is '0\n1\n2\n0\n1\n2\n' instead of '0\n0\n1\n1\n2\n2\n'.

Comment: it is as if the 'sort' that perl does sort it also by asc filename or input (sdin, file by file) as well, not only by the content of date & time of the whole sdin.

Comment: I think I understand what's going on....
Any chance your perl script is working differently on Solaris then Centos ?

Comment: I think I found the reason... LC_TIME is different between centos ( that suggested perl sort command above works ) and solaris ( where it don't sort as expeted ).
in my case LC_ALL / LC_TIME /LC_LANG etc all defined as 'en_US.UTF-8' but when I check 'locale -k LC_TIME' I see discrepancies between fields ( e.g. d_fmt, date_fmt  are not identical between centos and solaris ).

Comment: I think unless these field will be identical - perl's sort won't behave the same.
problem is - AFAIK LC_* definisions (i.e 'en_US.UTF-8' ) suppose to be ISO/standart - so how on earth their field as still different between two OSs ?

Comment: @gps3dx, that `perl` code doesn't use locale information.

Comment: then how the perl sort differences between centos 7 and solaris 11 can be explained ?

Answer (score 0):

To sort null-separated records, if there's a character that's guaranteed not to appear in your data, you can use `tr` to swap it with null bytes. However that won't help you directly since your data is separated by newlines, and even GNU sort doesn't have an option to treat only certain newlines as separators. You need to translate newline-tab sequences to something that doesn't contain a newline, then sort, then undo the original translation.

Assuming that your data doesn't contain tabs other than a single tab at the beginning of some lines, the translation can be to remove newlines before tabs, and add them back after sorting.

```
awk '/^\t/ {line = line $0; next}
     {print line; line = $0}
     END {print line}' |
sort |
awk '{gsub(/\t/, "\n\t"); print}'
```